# How many non-decreasing sequences of finite length do exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Given a finite set of numbers $A=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$. How many sequences $a_{1} a_{2}...a_{n}$ of length $n$ with $a_i\in A$ and
$a_i \le a_{i+1} $ for $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\} $ do exist?

Obviously, if $a_i=m$, there are $m$ possible numbers for position $i+1$, but i can't get this idea into an equation.

Any help?

Comment: Can elements of $A$ be repeated in your sequence? What is the relationship between $k$ and $n$?

Comment: Yes, they can occur more than once and there are no restrictions for the relation of $k $ to $n $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for a given list $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ a new list $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ where $b_i=a_i+i-1$. Now $$1\leq b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_n\leq k+n-1$$ and $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ can be any subset of $n$ elements chosen from $1,\ldots,k+n-1$. There are $$\binom{n+k-1}n$$ such subsets, hence that many lists $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$

Comment: Do I understand right, that $b_i=a_i+i-1$ gives a bijection from non decreasing sequences of length $n$ over $\{1,...,k\} $ to increasing sequences of length $n$ over $\{1,...,n+k-1\}$? The function seems clearly injective, but why is it surjective?

Comment: Okay, i get it. Of course, it is surjective. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Call $u(k,m)$ the number you are looking for.

The base cases are $u(0,m)=0$ and $u(k,0)=1$.

Now, $u(k,m+1)=\sum_{i=1}^k u(i,m)$.

This gives you an algorithm to compute them. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a close formula for $u(k,m)$. For instance:

$u(k,1)=k$,

$u(k,2)=k(k+1)/2$,

$u(k,3)=k(k+1)/4+k(k+1)(2k+1)/12$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't the sum should run from $1$ to $k $?